# I run ng build separately on dotnet project from then I am getting 'Cannot read property 'id' of undefined' error

Tags: .net, angular

I have a dotnet 3.1 project which uses angular10 for the front end. The project has no errors. It was working fine. I used to run it from the visual studio with the start button. I tried to build the project with the 'ng-build' command though it's not needed.
Now my, project is not working. I checked everything, deleted the dist folder, undo everything, nothing is changed. But, I am getting this error.

```
core.js:24904 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:24904)
    at core.js:24915
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:24915)
    at new NgModuleFactory (core.js:25018)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (core.js:28655)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:28881)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:15)
```

I don't know what's wrong. It happened before. I have to delete the project and clone again. Why does this happen? Any idea?

I checked in the core.js in the chrome inspector. It's stopping at this point.
`if (ngModuleType.ɵmod.id !== null) {`

Comment: Have you tried deleting `node_modules` and doing an `npm install`?

Comment: I didn't. But I didn't install anything new. Do you think the ng-build command updates any packages automatically? Anyways I will try it. Thanks.